# PYTHONPATH showing empty in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, pythonpath, robotframework

when i do `echo $PYTHONPATH`  it returns nothing..empty line.

so what does that mean. Im using python and it's working fine ..so whats the use of pythonpath and what should be the value of this in ubuntu 13.04

`/usr/bin/`

or

`/usr/lib/`

..or something else

and in windows we have python27/source  directory where i could put external sources/drivers , where(or equivalent) it is in ubuntu.

when I do `user@user$ dpkg -L python2.7` it shows

```
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib2to3
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib2to3/fixer_util.py
....
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib2to3/Grammar.txt
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/python2.7
/usr/share/doc/python2.7/NEWS.gz
/usr/share/doc/python2.7/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/python2.7/ACKS.gz
/usr/share/doc/python2.7/README.gz
/usr/share/doc/python2.7/copyright
/usr/share/lintian
/usr/share/lintian/overrides
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/python2.7
/usr/share/applications
/usr/share/applications/python2.7.desktop
/usr/share/menu
/usr/share/menu/python2.7
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/2to3-2.7.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/pdb2.7.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/pygettext2.7.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/pydoc2.7.1.gz
/usr/share/pixmaps
/usr/share/pixmaps/python2.7.xpm
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/2to3-2.7
/usr/bin/pygettext2.7
/usr/bin/pydoc2.7
/usr/share/doc/python2.7/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/python2.7/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/bin/pdb2.7
```

I've downloaded chrome driver from this site and put in given directory`/usr/bin`..but it's not working .where should i put this?
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The variable `PYTHONPATH` that you echo in the terminal is added to the other paths of python. So if you don't have any particular path set in your `.profile` or `.bashrc` file (or locally), the variable will be empty.

To see the path that python uses do in a python shell

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

Or as @mgilson suggestes, you can run from terminal

```
python -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'
```

---

A note: If you decide to install by hand a package using `python setup.py install --user` you don't need to add `$HOME/.local/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages` to `PYTHONPATH`, as it is already in `sys.path`

Comment: or, `python -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'` from a regular shell ;-)

Comment: @mgilson: thanks for saving me the bother to remember the option `-c` :D

Comment: No problem -- I tend to use it pretty frequently to do stupid stuff like this.  I frequently find myself doing stuff like `python -c 'import matplotlib; print matplotlib.__version__` or the like...

Answer (score 1):

If you want Python to have some extra set of paths in it's `sys.path` in every Python session apart from the default ones (`site-packages` etc) you add it to the `$PYTHONPATH` environment (local or system) variable.

Most probably you don't need it right now, leave it as it is.

Plus you'll know when you really need it populate it.

If you use `site.addsitedir("path")` in almost every Python path then you can add that `"path"` to `$PYTHONPATH`.

Check [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv).

Comment: @GauravJain: if you install by hand, do `python setup.py install --user`. It will install in `$HOME/.local/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages`. So you're sure that it won't interfere with system-wide packages

Comment: @GauravJain -- Usually you're supposed to *install* packages.  I'm not too familiar with `selenium` or `chromedriver`, but python code is generally packaged with a `setup.py` script that you should run as an admin to install it...